# How to pass strong quoting as parameter to bash function

Tags: bash, awk

I have been trying to send parameter which also contains strong quoting but have been unsuccessful till now. I am trying to write a code something like this among with lots of variant which are also not working as expected :

```
diffFile()
{
    cat dir1/$1 | "$2"
}

diffFile "chkconfig" "awk '{print $1}'"
```

But the problem is when i run the script the strong quoting gets escaped.
How can i pass the strong quoting?

Comment: Don't do it: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: I just needed it for simple cases. Anyways thanks for your valuable reply. I will not use it in complex cases :)

Comment: Why are you even doing it this way ? awk takes files as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Ok got a solution after playing with my script.

```
diffFile()
{
  cat dir1/$1 | eval "$2"
}

diffFile "chkconfig" "awk '{print \$1}'"
```

Comment: The use of `eval` is discouraged. Take a moment and ask yourself *what* the purpose of `diffFile` is. Is it a general wrapper that feeds a file in `dirt` to an arbitrary shell command that reads standard input?